# [catkin_make] Cmake Error

Tags: ros, youbot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone.
I'm doing this thing (youbot ros-hydro-wrapper-for-kuka-youbot) trying to make youbot by Kuka working and there's an error on the last "$ catkin_make".

```
$ cd ~/catkin_ws/src
    $ git clone github.com /youbot/youbot_driver_ros_interface.git -b hydro-devel
$ cd ..
$ catkin_make
$ sudo setcap cap_net_raw+ep devel/lib/youbot_driver_ros_interface/youbot_driver_ros_interface
```

it's my first time with Ubuntu and ROS, so I don't really know what gone wrong.

> CMake Error at
> /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:72
> (find_package):   Could not find a
> package configuration file provided by
> "brics_actuator"   with any of the
> following names:
>
> ```
> brics_actuatorConfig.cmake
> brics_actuator-config.cmake
> ```
>
> Add the installation prefix of
> "brics_actuator" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
> or set   "brics_actuator_DIR" to a
> directory containing one of the above
> files.  If   "brics_actuator" provides
> a separate development package or SDK,
> be sure it   has been installed. Call
> Stack (most recent call first):
> youbot_driver_ros_interface/CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package)
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! make: ***
> [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
> Invoking "make
> cmake_check_build_system" failed

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/138236/%5Bcatkin_make%5D-cmake-error/) by [runout](https://answers.ros.org/users/13096/runout/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-03-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like the youbot driver requires the brics_actuator package but you have not installed it on your system or put it in your workspace. You'll need to resolve that dependency before you can build that package.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [runout](https://answers.ros.org/users/13096/runout/) on 2014-03-29**:
Thanks, well the next question will be: how to do that.
I've found brics_actuator git, but I really new at linux so I have no idea what to do with that. :(

**Comment by [runout](https://answers.ros.org/users/13096/runout/) on 2014-03-29**:
found it. That's what I was needed.
brics_actuator. [$ sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-brics-actuator]
pr2_msgs. [$ sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-pr2-msgs]

Now I got new problem with:
[youbot_driver.launch] is neither a launch file in package [youbot_driver_ros_interface] nor is [youbot_driver_ros_interface] a launch file name
But I guess that's another question.

**Comment by [ratneshmadaan](https://answers.ros.org/users/12636/ratneshmadaan/) on 2014-05-15**:
$ sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-youbot-driver-ros-interface

I edited the youbot-ethercat config file from eth0 to eth1 (path is /opt/ros/hydro/share/youbot_driver/config, you'll need sudo access to edit it).
But I am getting an error
[ERROR] [1400149466.933178411]: No EtherCAT connection:
[FATAL] [1400149466.933450442]: No socket connection on eth1
Excecute as root
(I have the manipulator at eth1 only.) Help please?

**Comment by [CroCo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4955/croco/) on 2022-08-18**:
For Simulation, how to bypass that error? I'm not intended to use the real hardware. Any suggestions!